# How can I put the discovered values into loop variables so that they are on one line

Tags: ansible

How can I put the discovered values into loop variables so that they are on one line using Ansible task? I have now task like this

```
- name: Updating test.conf
  lineinfile:
    path: "/root/test.conf"
    regexp: "test="
    line: "test={{ hostvars[item]['ansible_env'].SSH_CONNECTION.split(' ')[2] }}"
    state: present
  with_nested: 
    - "{{groups['app']}}"
```

It needs that when invoking the job, it takes the IP addresses from the servers that are in the app group and puts them on a single line. Currently, it performs such a substitution twice with which they are replaced and finally there is only one address in the test parameter.

I need format after task like this:

```
test=1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

While jinja2 is heavily inspired from python, its does not allow you to do all the same operations. To join a list your would have to do something like:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ myvar | join(',') }}"
  vars:
    myvar:
      - foo
      - bar
```

When in doubt, always use a simple playwook with a debug task to validate your jinja code.